# Datetime in json string is getting converted to localtime

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Why is the datetime+offset is getting converted to localtime+offset when convert the json string to Jobject.

Here is the code.

```
string dataValue = @"{""Time"":""2016-07-15T20:03:41+08:00""}";
JObject json = JObject.Parse(dataValue);
Console.Write(json.ToString());
```

Output:

```
{
  "Time": "2016-07-15T17:33:41+05:30"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "Time": "2016-07-15T20:03:41+08:00"
}
```

Comment: Which json parser?  Newtonsoft?

Comment: Yes, its newtonsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it will be using the local time, but you can override the default settings:

```
var dataValue = @"{""Time"":""2016-07-15T20:03:41+08:00""}";

var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(dataValue, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

If you don't care about the date being converted to a **DateTime** type, you can tell **Json.NET** to just ignore dates and parse the value as a **string**:

```
var dataValue = @"{""Time"":""2016-07-15T20:03:41+08:00""}";

var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
};

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(dataValue, jsonSerializerSettings)
```

In such a way it will stay exactly as your input.

Comment: This converting to utc and removing the offset("Time": "2016-07-15T12:03:41Z"), I  want to retain the original timezone and offset

Comment: The literal "Z" is the ISO 8601 date time standard for UTC times, if you want the offset, you can change the format property of the `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Comment: setting DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None worked for me

Comment: @KhanS sure, but don't forget that with None it won't even parse it as a date, it will leave it as a string!